# Help identifying this connector - it looks like a smaller version of mini-DIN

Tags: connector

Does anyone recognise this connector? It is used as the power connector on a Targus universal laptop docking station. It is 10mm diameter, 4 pins. Similar to but smaller than the one on the right which is a 4-pin Mini-DIN. (The one I bought before I checked the dimensions.)

[image: Mystery Connector on the left]

Comment: You sure about that? The left one looks like mini-DIN to me and the right one some strange larger variant.

Comment: Google finds it easily with '4 pin 10mm din notch' image search.

Comment: Does this look like it? http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/222/KPPX-365228.pdf

Comment: @winny - Thanks. The one on the right is what I got when I ordered a 4-pin mini-DIN from ebay.

Comment: @Tut, you should make an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typical power plug on high-powered laptops, Such as Alienware, Acer or Clevo. It appears to be called "DIN-4pin".

Comment: Thanks. @tut above pointed me to the plug, which is what I'm looking for.